# Download file in Express route, serve to the client, then remove

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I have an internal HTTP Post API that generates files, size 5-10mb each. This service is not modifiable.
I want to "proxy" this file download through the public API, which is based on Node.js+Express. However, I can't figure out the best way of doing so.

I guess I can download this file with Axios into a temporary file in the Node.js API container, but that seems to be prone to issues with these temporary files potentially piling up and requiring later cleanup. Is there a way to achieve such file download -> send further to a client without creating a temporary file?
Or what would be the most efficient and "clean" way of doing so if temporary files are unavoidable?

```
router.post('/route/:someid',
    [someRequestVerificationMiddleware],
    (req, res, next) => {
      const myFileId = req.params.someid;

      const downloadRequestParams= {
        "id": myFileId 
      };
      let dlPromise = axios.post(`http://myinternalservice:80`,
          downloadRequestParams, {responseType: "stream"});
      dlPromise.then(response => {
        try {
          let filename = response.headers["x-result-filename"];

          //
          // What would be the most efficient way to return the received file
          // from response data to the client calling this route without creating
          // too much garbage?
          //
          

        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
        }
      })
          .catch(e=>{
            console.error(e);
          res.status(500);
      })
          .finally(() => {
            next();
      })
    });

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: FYI, you don't call `next()` in a request handler that sends a response.  You only call `next()` in middleware when you want routing to continue to other route handlers - one of which will send a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`res` is a stream.  You can simply pipe your axios stream to the response.

```
    res.setHeader("content-type", "...");
    return dlPromise.then((response) => response.data.pipe(res));
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. For the future reference, I also added `res.setHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);` for suggesting the name of the redirected file download. So that it's not simply `response`.